# Añadir dos elementos td al mismo nivel en una variable con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

He creado un elemento con jquery de la siguiente manera

```
var x = $("<tr><td> Contenido </td></tr>");
```

el resultado si es lo que espero, ahora quiero agregar un nuevo tr al antes del creado y uno después del creado necesito que una vez que agregue x al html este sea mi resultado, he probado con append y prepend y no obtengo mi resultado

```
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contenido</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Cuando pretendo hacer estas inserciones aún no lo he agregado al html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```
var temporal = $("<table><tbody></tbody></table>"); // crear una tabla temporal
var x = $("<tr><td> Contenido</td></tr>");

x.appendTo(temporal); // agregar **x** a la tabla temporal

$("<tr><td></td></tr>").prependTo(temporal); // poner fila vacia antes de x
$("<tr><td></td></tr>").appendTo(temporal);  // poner una fila vacia luego de x


var contenido = $(temporal).html()  // extraes lo que necesitas
```

el valor de la variable **contenido** será:

```
<tbody>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Contenido</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

---

y si lo que buscas es seleccionar el contenido de tbody usa:

```
var contenido = $("tbody", temporal).html()
```

y el valor de la variable contenido será:

```
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contenido</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
para obtener el primero y el ultimo elemento e insertar:
`before()` o `after()`

```
$('tbody tr').first();

$('tbody tr').last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con prepend(para agregar contenido antes) y append(para agregar contenido despues):

```js
var x = $("<tr><td> Contenido </td></tr>");
x.prepend("<tr><td>antes</td></tr>");
x.append("<tr><td>despues</td></tr>");
$('tbody').append(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>y</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```